# .PivotCache.Refresh not working

Tags: vba, excel

I included all the code in case there was something that is causing this but I dont think there is. If I step through the code the last line works properly. If I run it in real time it does not. Any thoughts?

```
Sub Updatequery()
For a = 1 To 2
oldconnstring = ActiveWorkbook.Connections(a).ODBCConnection.Connection
Debug.Print oldconnstring
P1 = Left(oldconnstring, 9)
P2 = Mid(oldconnstring, InStr(10, oldconnstring, ";"), 8)
P3 = Mid(oldconnstring, (InStr(10, oldconnstring, "DATABASE") - 11), 20)
P4 = Mid(oldconnstring, (InStr(10, oldconnstring, "AUTHENTIC") - 1), 200)
O1 = Worksheets("Data").Cells(2, 4).Value
O2 = Worksheets("Data").Cells(2, 5).Value
newconnstring = P1 & O2 & P2 & O1 & P3 & Replace(O2, "_", "") & P4
Debug.Print oldconnstring
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections(a).ODBCConnection
    .Connection = newconnstring
 End With

Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Connections(a).ODBCConnection.Connection
ActiveWorkbook.Connections(a).Refresh
DoEvents
Next a
DoEvents
Sheets("Summary").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SummaryP").PivotCache.Refresh
```

Comment: Do you need to have a line before to say `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SummaryP").PivotCache.BackgroundQuery = False`?

Comment: In fact it'll likely still be the previous refresh which means you should do: `ActiveWorkbook.Connections(a).BackgroundQuery = False`

Comment: I believe that's it! Thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries. I could put it as an answer then!

Answer (score 1):

You need the following in before each refresh:
 `ActiveWorkbook.Connections(a).BackgroundQuery = False`

Comment: your solution kept giving me errors but got me in the right direction .. I added     .BackgroundQuery = False
    .Refresh to the with clause above and that did the trick.